# Finding an item without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a set of DIVs with different classes. There is about 40 divs with 4 classes set randomly. I need a JQuery script that makes "background-color: white" on every grid-item I click. I tried this:

```
$('.grid-item').click(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "white");
})
```

But that wasn't a good idea i guess..
..because it didn't work!

Can you help me out, please?

Comment: Does your function get called on click? Can you access any properties on `$(this)` in your code?

Comment: I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bohpko8/1/), and your code seems to work without error, and did what you expect, maybe you have to create one to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "didn't work" meant or show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', 'div',
function(e){
   $(this).css("background-color","white");
});
```